# JOIN query using Room

Tags: android, join, android-room

I am new to Room database and I am trying to figure out how to use the JOIN query.
So I have 2 tables (entities):

> 1."Medication" which contains the fields: med_id, name, mg, amountOfReminders
>
> 2."Reminder" which contains the fields: reminder_id, hour, minutes, amountOfDoses, dayToRemind.

Now I need to return a List that contains some fields from Medication table (such as name, mg) and some fields from Reminder table (such as hour, minutes, doses and day). I am wondering where should this query be placed. Is it in MedicationDao or ReminderDao or maybe another Dao?
Should I also have a class that contains the join fields (as the type of the List to return)?
I am very confused and couldn't find any unambiguous answer for that.
Thanks!

Comment: Medication and Reminder is one to one relation or one to many? For example, for one medication you will have many reminders

Comment: It is one-to-many. For one medication you could have many reminders